# Using R keyring library in batch Rscript produces "key is not a string (length 1 character)" error

Tags: r, linux, security, passwords, rscript

The following R script running on RHEL 7.7 is producing a "key is not a string (length 1 character)" error when executed from the command line using RScript. The password was successfully set within the R environment using key_set("TESTSERVICE","TESTUSER") to the default keyring and the password is accessible from the interactive R environment using key_get("TESTSERVICE","TESTUSER") but not when using Rscript (or R CMD BATCH).  No results on SO or Google search with the error message.
**Has anyone encountered this and resolved it?**

**test_keyring.R**

```
library(keyring)
key_get("TESTSERVICE","TESTUSER")
```

**Command**: `Rscript test_keyring.R`

**Output**: `Error: key is not a string (length 1 character) Execution halted`